need to add the job of one stage from another stage, with artifact files
I want to run the unit-test script code into sonar-app stage and artifact files too , so I want to call the unit-test job into my sonar-app, how to call any one please suggest me solution, Now I am calling only the dependencies of unit-test into my sonar-app stage , but it is not working
unit-test:
  stage: test
  image: node:14.21.3-alpine
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache chromium
    - export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
    - cd xx/app/
    - npm install --legacy-peer-deps
    - npm run unit-test
  allow_failure: false  
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - xxx/p/coverage/*
    expire_in: 1 day  
  tags:
    - automation
    - gcp
    - gke
    - k8s
    - pbc


sonar-app:
  <<: *tpl_build_gcp
  stage: sonar_audit
  image:
    name: europe-docker.pkg.dev/xxxxx-adm-ope-ope-d2/docker-shared-skf-xxxxx/sonar-scanner-cli:latest-release
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache chromium
    - export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
    - cd app
    
    - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_HOST_URL} -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_TOKEN} -Dsonar.projectKey=xxx -Dsonar.sources=src -Dsonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/*.html -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.tests=src -Dsonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts -Dsonar.javacript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/report-lcov/lcov.info -Dsonar.verbose=true
    # - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_HOST_URL} -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_TOKEN}
    allow_failure: false
  dependencies:
    - unit-test

